# How to eliminate the exponential result in this case

Tags: java

if the Value is something like this (0.0007 ) ends with 3 zeros after decimal , i am getting the result as 4.0E-4
.

Please tell me how to fix this

This is my program .

```
package com;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            String result = "";
            Test test = new Test();
            double value = 0.0004;
            if (value < 1) {
                result = test.numberFormat(value, 4);
            } else {
                result = test.numberFormat(value, 2);
            }
            System.out.println(result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public String numberFormat(double d, int decimals) {
        if (2 == decimals)
            return new DecimalFormat("#,###,###,##0.00").format(d);
        else if (0 == decimals)
            return new DecimalFormat("#,###,###,##0").format(d);
        else if (3 == decimals)
            return new DecimalFormat("#,###,###,##0.000").format(d);
        else if (4 == decimals)
            new DecimalFormat("#,###,###,##0.00##").format(d);
        return String.valueOf(d);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just forgot the return statement.

```
else if (4 == decimals)
    return new DecimalFormat("#,###,###,##0.00##").format(d);
```

So in the `4` case, you use `DecimalFormat` to format your number, but then return just the normal string representation for the double, after the final else.

Answer (score 2):

How about this instead:

```
public static String numberFormat(double d, int decimals) {
    return String.format("%." + decimals + "f", d);
}
```

Seems cleaner than what you're currently doing.